# Node JS & Sequelize: .findByPk returns me a function instead an object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize, Node, and Express in their latest versions.

I have a model called "Producers", eventProducers in the table name with the following columns:

```
"id"
"name"
"email"
"url"
"description"
"createdAt"
"updatedAt"
"deletedAt"
```

I'm trying to build the view of the object with this function:

```
export async function renderViewProducer(req, res) {
    try {
        const producer = await Producer.findByPk(req.params.id).toJSON;
        if (producer) {
            console.log('Producer: ', producer);
            console.log('id: ', producer.id);
            res.render('components/producers/view-producer', {producer});
        } else {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'La Productora que intenta ver no existe');
            res.redirect('/producers');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Ha ocurrido un error interno, por favor contacte al administrador');
        res.redirect('/producers');
    }
};
```

I'm using the try/catch instead of the Then function, maybe I'm having the issue there.
I'm still a little bit confused about Promises.

This is what I found in the documentation:

```
public static async findByPk(param: number | string | Buffer, options: object): Promise<Model>
```

I'm sure that the issue must be here, I'm not getting the Model. Don't know why

This is my Console Log:

```
Producer:  [Function]
id:  undefined
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "email", "url", "description", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt" FROM "eventProducers" AS "eventProducer" WHERE ("eventProducer"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND "eventProducer"."id" = 'bac1ce11-0cb9-4d8c-88b3-558c168b8cbd');
```

I've copy&paste the query at PGAdmin and works fine.

I'm getting Producer as a function and the Id undefined.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toJSON` is a function, you should call it after receiving an instance of the model:

```js
export async function renderViewProducer(req, res) {
    try {
        const producerModel = await Producer.findByPk(req.params.id);
        const producer = producerModel.toJSON();
        if (producer) {
            console.log('Producer: ', producer);
            console.log('id: ', producer.id);
            res.render('components/producers/view-producer', {producer});
        } else {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'La Productora que intenta ver no existe');
            res.redirect('/producers');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Ha ocurrido un error interno, por favor contacte al administrador');
        res.redirect('/producers');
    }
};
```

The only thing I don’t understand is why you use the `toJSON` method in this code.
If you want to get a plain object, not a model instance, then you need to use `producerModel.get({plain: true})`:

```js
export async function renderViewProducer(req, res) {
    try {
        const producerModel = await Producer.findByPk(req.params.id);
        const producer = producerModel.get({plain: true});
        if (producer) {
            console.log('Producer: ', producer);
            console.log('id: ', producer.id);
            res.render('components/producers/view-producer', {producer});
        } else {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'La Productora que intenta ver no existe');
            res.redirect('/producers');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Ha ocurrido un error interno, por favor contacte al administrador');
        res.redirect('/producers');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rustam, you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

I've been like 3 years without writing code so I feel a little bit rusty.
You just solve my problem with two simple lines.

I started using `toJSON()` since I was trying to list all the producers and got stuck with the **"Access has been denied to resolve the property "..." because it is not an "own property" of its parent."** [GitHub](https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/1642)
I took the solution from that post so this is my function:

```
export async function renderProducers(req, res) {
    try {
        let producers = await Producer.findAll();
        res.render('components/producers/all-producers', {
            producers: producers.map(producers => producers.toJSON())
        });
    } catch (error) {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Algo falló al mostrar las productoras');
    }
};
```

I guess I need to use the `Model.get({plain: true})` instead of that.